# Intercept Opengl Calls and Replay them in other window

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I've written my openg32.dll to replace the origin. In the dll I create a window to replay the opengl calls.

My code:

```
void WINAPI sys_wglSwapBuffers(HDC hdc)
{
    HDC l_oldDC = sys_wglGetCurrentDC();  
    HGLRC l_oldRC = sys_wglGetCurrentContext();  
    (*orig_wglSwapBuffers)(hdc); 
    //hDC is the dc of the window created by me
    sys_wglMakeCurrent(hDC, l_oldRC);  
    (*orig_wglSwapBuffers)(hDC);  
    sys_wglMakeCurrent(l_oldDC, l_oldRC);  

}
```

Other opengl functions is like :

```
void WINAPI sys_glVertex3f (GLfloat x,  GLfloat y,  GLfloat z)
{

    HDC l_oldDC = sys_wglGetCurrentDC();  
    HGLRC l_oldRC = sys_wglGetCurrentContext();  
        // default call
    (*orig_glVertex3f) (x, y, z);

    sys_wglMakeCurrent(hDC, l_oldRC);  
    (*orig_glVertex3f) (x, y, z);
    sys_wglMakeCurrent(l_oldDC, l_oldRC);  
}
```

I want to copy the opengl calls and display on the window that created by the dll .
But It does not work. each one (the application and the created window) display nothing.
I don't know how to modify it?

Comment: You shouldn't change the original "opengl32.dll", *as commented and answered in your previous, almost the same question.* As this reaaally fast turns into something reaally ugly.

Comment: What Vellentin is trying to say is, that you *must not* replace opengl32.dll at all. And your own interception DLL must not be named opengl32.dll. Instead you must hook into the DLL loading. Google for "Windows DLL hooking" or "Windows DLL injection". Be advised that many Anti Virus will detect this as potentially malicious behavior. This looks like a nice starting point: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/hooking/article.php/c127/APIHijack--A-Library-for-Easy-DLL-Function-Hooking.htm

Comment: Well. If one _really_ knows what one is doing, one can completely replace `opengl32.dll` on windows. And load the ICD directly. But I agree that it is a pointless waste of time, usually. However, hooking into the DLL is not really required, either. Just placing the own `opengl.dll` in the same directory as the target exe and internally loading the MS one will work fine, and that is also what [chromium](http://chromium.sf.net) did on windows.

Comment: You can use a local replace of opengl32.dll in the application folder and leave the system one alone. That's how GLIntercept (https://code.google.com/p/glintercept/) works.